# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf, el

I have this form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Entrez un id du compte a supprimer" for="id"/>
    <h:inputText id="id" value=""/>
    <h:commandButton id="supprimer" value="Supprimer" action="#{compteBancaireMBean.supprimer}"/>  
</h:form>
```

And this action method:

```
public String supprimer() {  
    gestionnaireDeCompteBancaire.supprimer(comptebancaire.getId());  
    return "CompteList";  
}
```

When I submit the form, I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /Supprimer.xhtml @14,44 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value=""` does not mean anything to the JSF el parser, it can't make sense of that. You need to actually provide a static value there, as in `value="Some Text"` or bind it to a variable in your backing bean as in `value="#{compteBancaireMBean.myVariable}"` where `myVariable` corresponds to an actual variable in your `compteBancaireMBean` backing bean. This variable must follow the javabean conventions i.e. you must have

```
   private Integer myVariable;  //I use Integer here just as an example, you can use any core java type

   public void setMyVariable(Integer myVariable){
    this.myVariable = myVariable 
   }

   public Integer getMyVariable(){
   return this.myVariable
   }
```