# h:commandButton click causes javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException

Tags: jsf, el

Whenever I try to execute some JavaScript code on my XHTML JSF pages I get the following error:

**Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation**

```
<h:commandButton onclick="addTest()" styleClass="btn-primary" value="Add Test"></h:commandButton>

<div class="labTest"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addTest()
{ 
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".labTest").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");
 });
}
</script>
```

Now I am trying to populate the `.labTest` div with some html code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have $(".labTest").html("<b>Hello world!</b>"); and not $("#labTest").html("<b>Hello world!</b>");

Comment: Hi Jasper. I am very new to JSF. I have always written code in PHP for web apps and Java for desktop apps or web back end. Now I am trying to use JSF and I have that error. Kindly advise how I should edit the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasper. I had an input field as follows: <f:inputText id="test_results" value=" "></f:inputText> I think it was making an attempt to map  value=" "  to a bean property. Following the link you gave me opened my mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /Supprimer.xhtml @14,44 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714081/javax-el-propertynotwritableexception-supprimer-xhtml-14-44-value-illegal)

Comment: Next time please post the full stacktrace (contains valuable information, see the 'duplicate')

Comment: Noted with thanks.